# The file /app/chromedriver does not exist

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I created the `Image` of my `.net-core API` but when I try to run it I face with this error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The file /app/chromedriver does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
         at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService..ctor(String servicePath, Int32 port, String driverServiceExecutableName, Uri driverServiceDownloadUrl)
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriverService..ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port, Uri downloadUrl)
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService..ctor(String executablePath, String executableFileName, Int32 port)
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(String driverPath, String driverExecutableFileName)
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(String driverPath)
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
         at Pand.Application.Scraper.UpdatePriceScraper.Start() in /src/Pand.Application/Scraper/UpdatePriceScraper.cs:line 35
         at Pand.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /src/Pand/Startup.cs:line 114
         at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I tried to put `chromedriver.exe` in `/app` folder but I still have this error. It is important to mention that I reviewed the same questions but I could not find the solution.
Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ["NuGet.Config", "."]
    COPY ["Pand/Pand.csproj", "Pand/"]
    COPY ["Pand.Application/Pand.Application.csproj", "Pand.Application/"]
    COPY ["Pand.Domain/Pand.Domain.csproj", "Pand.Domain/"]
    COPY ["Pand.Infrastructure/Pand.Infrastructure.csproj", "Pand.Infrastructure/"]
    
    COPY ["Pand/chromedriver.exe", "."]
    
    RUN dotnet restore "Pand/Pand.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/Pand"
    RUN dotnet build "Pand.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
    
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "Pand.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
    
    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pand.dll"]
```

As you see I added

> COPY ["Pand/chromedriver.exe", "."]

, but seemingly this file is not transfered to `Docker Container`.

And these are my command for creating and running Docker.

> docker build -t Pandgroup/backend -f Pand/Dockerfile .
>
> docker run -p 8080:80 Pandgroup/backend

Comment: The error says it's looking for the chromedriver exectuable in the /app directory, but you seem to be copying it to the /src directory

Comment: @johndee31415 Correct, but what changes should I make to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WORKDIR /app` before COPY chromedriver command. Otherwise it comes to /src

Comment: I get "=> ERROR [build 10/13] RUN dotnet restore "Pandora/Pandora.csproj" error while building image. In addition, I wrote it in the line 2 (before everything).

Comment: After copy chromedriver go back to /src: WORKDIR /src

Comment: I added `WORKDIR /app` exactly before copy commands but I get ' => ERROR [build 13/13] RUN dotnet build "Pandora.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build'

Comment: You should update your question to track changes. But I will appreciate if you accept my answer on your question about chromedriver.

Comment: I updated my question. I will accept your answer but I still have a problem. Please give me a hand to solve it.

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app 
COPY ["Pand/chromedriver.exe", "."]

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NuGet.Config", "."]
COPY ["Pand/Pand.csproj", "Pand/"]
COPY ["Pand.Application/Pand.Application.csproj", "Pand.Application/"]
COPY ["Pand.Domain/Pand.Domain.csproj", "Pand.Domain/"]
COPY ["Pand.Infrastructure/Pand.Infrastructure.csproj", "Pand.Infrastructure/"]

Comment: It built successfully but I still have 'The file /app/chromedriver does not exist.' error

Comment: FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=build /src/chromedriver.exe .
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pand.dll"]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246503/discussion-between-sasan-karimi-and-kesha).